# Nullable DateTime in Html Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, html-helper, nullable

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I am trying to add a field to edit a date. The date is a nullable DateTime object. What I was trying to do was create 3 input boxes (Month, Day, and Year) and have them be linked to the model. I want it to display the date components in those boxes when there is a date set. When there's not, it should not have any value and just display the placeholder.

[image]

I'm using html helpers to do this (though this is not a requirement), but I cannot get it to work when the date is null.

Here's what I have currently:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active_Date_Start.Value.Month, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control active-date", @placeholder = "MM", @maxlength = "2" } }) /
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active_Date_Start.Value.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control active-date", @placeholder = "DD", @maxlength = "2" } }) /
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active_Date_Start.Value.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control active-date", @placeholder = "YYYY", @maxlength = "4" } })
```

This works when the date is not null, but causes an error when it is.

The other approach I tried was to use pure html to create these input boxes, and then assemble the date myself on the backend when the form is submitted. I couldn't get this to work because I couldn't figure out how to conditionally set the value of the inputs.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is pointless since it would never bind to your `DateTime?` property when you submit anyway. Your view model needs to contain 3 properties for the day, month and year (and then a lot of extra code to validate the values on both the client and server, and to build your `DateTime` value). Why are you not just using a jquery datepicker?

Comment: Because I haven't done a lot of work with jquery and didn't know it was a thing. Haha. That ought to solve my problem. Thanks for the tip!